# Setting a cookie upon login in Spring Security 3.0

Tags: session, jsp, cookies, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to set a cookie when someone logs in and the JSP page that comes up needs to be able to read that cookie in Javascript and perform an action based on it.  The part I'm stuck on is setting a cookie upon login.  I'm using Spring 3.0 and Spring Security 3.0.

I've registered a LoginListener:

```
public class LoginListener implements ApplicationListener {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            somehowGetResponseObject.addCookie(new Cookie(name, value));
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I can also get the request object so I can find the contextPath and set that as the cookie path.  I'm fine with adding the cookie to a ThreadLocal object and then reading that later when I do have access to a response object, but is there a later time when I would have that access?  I'm not so enthusiastic about adding the cookie to a Session and then reading that in the resulting JSP page, but I'll do that if I have to.  Can I get access to the HttpSession?

***UPDATE***: Specifying an authentication-success-handler-ref solved this: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-flow-handling

Answer (score 2):

Something totally different, why don't you just print that value as if it's a JS variable?

```
<script>
    var something = '${somebean.someproperty}';
    if (something) {
        performActionWith(something);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I need to perform an action in javascript when someone logs in.  But that person can login and end up on any webpage, so I don't know the page before-hand that they're going to land on.

Comment: That's exactly why I added an `if` condition to the example. If the user is logged in, set bean property, if not make it null.

Comment: How do I know the user has just logged in?  I only want to perform the javascript action if the user JUST logged in for the first time in this session.

Comment: You used `if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent)` for this in your question. I don't do Spring, but if this is working, then it's perfectly doable. You just have to set some Spring bean property which you then print as if it's a JS variable.